# How to combine columns of unequal length and make them equal in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

If I have two separate tables (names and colors) and have the following columns:

**name**
John
Amy
Jack
Ray
Jane
Flo

**colors**
red
green

How do I make it so I get
**name color**
John  red
Amy   green
Jack  red
Ray   green
Jane  red
Flo   green

I am using postgreSQL-9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird use case, but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT name || ' ' || color
FROM names, colors
WHERE length(name || ' ' || color) = 8
```